# Get Views Of A Facebook Video Using Public API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I want to download statistics on a Facebook video, I can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video to get almost all the public information about a video expect for its view count. Is there someway to get the view count from videos on Facebook page from the API without having access to pages insights?

Comment: Try VIDEO INSIGHTS as I explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38993938/552322

Answer (score 2):

Video in a Fan Page is treated as a POST, you can check the following link for the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights)

> Permissions
>
> Any valid access token can be used for publicly available metrics
>   (currently page_fans_country or page_storytellers_by_country). 
>   access token with read_insights permission can retrieve metrics for
>   all pages and domains owned by this user. A page access token with
>   read_insights permission can retrieve all metrics for that Page.A user

So the answer to your question is, it's not possible without the "read_insights permission".

Comment: not any more as of Graph API v.2.9. There is video_insight endpoint for videos, and you can't use the regular insights anymore for videos. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/

Comment: I am still getting empty data in response if use video_insights end point even though i am the owner of the video.?