# How to get the number of video's views in facebook

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

i'm using facebook graph api to get global video views first and then i want to try for individual ones but when i try this syntax:

GET /v2.5/{object-id}/insights/page_video_views?

i got this as an answer:

```
    {
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/insights/page_video_views?access_token=CAAHqSB13M38BADBeaD95DWV4ECBhy5xdGSR9jASunxK3J6TMwmpZA09wk9FoZAtDpyjIWhPqCbjy1PNy5dPXSMlMI9HE5ZA3m8Kbpq46r8YFauyOluPSYfBlCJJIzZCTEz3tfGoPKZBXMIq4LiTfRCmIggSDLLhsRL03a89JoeOgy15nu1ch71tmU7HU9JcZAsjCvZC4IdBggZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1458550344&until=1458809544",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/insights/page_video_views?access_token=CAAHqSB13M38BADBeaD95DWV4ECBhy5xdGSR9jASunxK3J6TMwmpZA09wk9FoZAtDpyjIWhPqCbjy1PNy5dPXSMlMI9HE5ZA3m8Kbpq46r8YFauyOluPSYfBlCJJIzZCTEz3tfGoPKZBXMIq4LiTfRCmIggSDLLhsRL03a89JoeOgy15nu1ch71tmU7HU9JcZAsjCvZC4IdBggZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1459068744&until=1459327944"
  }
}
```

knowing that i have all the permissions (i'am the one who created the page, i gave myself permissions and i have the access_token).

Why there's no data no information about the number of views ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the VIDEO INSIGHTS instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights

It gives you the stats you need but it's only for LIFETIME period. You can't specify date range unfortunately.

Comment: I am using the video insights but it is not giving me anything it is showing empty results..

Comment: @usama Same here. Is it because of the fact the page has less than 100 ppl liking it, does the rule apply to video insights as well?