# I want to scrape multiple facebook urls of my competitor's pages for video views count using python

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape facebook page url for video views count on my multiple competitor's pages. 
Problem is: Facebook Login.

What is the best way to login to facebook for scraping purpose. 
I looked around on stack overflow and other places. But most of those answers are outdated.

Comment: Take a look into facebook graph api. Much more easier than scraping facebook.

Comment: @salmanwahed Thanks for the response, I am familiar with graph api but i cannot get video views from that. I have to manually scrape, hence, login problem.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. you MUST use the graph api. if there is no way with the graph api, then it´s not possible.

Comment: See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/video/video_insights)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of video's views in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280351/how-to-get-the-number-of-videos-views-in-facebook)

Comment: @jdoe I am looking to get video views from my competitor's pages. I cannot access that using graph api.

Answer (score 0):

I found an Answer, i used requests module to login and scraped using BeautifulSoup. Login to facebook was not that easy though.